# Cannot log in to Windows account

Tags: windows, windows-10, window-manager

I am having trouble logging in to my desktop. When I enter my credentials, it says "signing in" and immediately signs out. I cannot see the desktop. The event log shows the following error:

```
The User Data Access_22a7cb7 service terminated with the following error:

Class not registered

The User Data Access_22a7cb7 service terminated with the following error:

There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
```

As a workaround, I have to log in to my admin account first, and then I can log in to this user account. This account has a 60-minute time interval, and after that, it signs out and gets killed. After the 60-minute interval, post signout, I cannot log in back unless I log in to my admin account.

Comment: It would appear you have made a registry change that has affected log in.  In a vanilla machine this does not happen.

Comment: How have you set up this 60-minute time interval ?

Comment: Also asked here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1387614/cannot-log-in-to-windows-account

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: I suggest running the following command: `FOR /R C:\ %G IN (*.dll) DO ["%systemroot%\system32\regsvr32.exe" /s "%G" regsvr32 ExplorerFrame.dll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1362339/the-user-data-access-2fd9d95d-service-terminated-w)

Answer (score 0):

This error is a registry error and apparently from changes you have made that have affected the log in.

The best way to try to repair is a Windows 10 Repair Install keeping data and let Windows rebuild itself.

> Go to the Windows Media Creation Link
>
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10
>
> Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally
> answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.
> Change this to Keep Data only.

If Keep Data does not work, the damage is either a User Profile damage or more serious OS damage.

In either case, back up and reinstall Windows.

Comment: An in-place repair install, will transfer whatever changes have been made, unless a clean install is selected. The author should identify what those changes were and reverse them.  If the machine is connected to an AD domain, then a repair install, will is a complete waste of time. In my opinion not yet enough is known about the machine's configuration to recommend a in-place repair. Of course I don't believe a registry modification was performed now that I have done my own research

Comment: That is why my last point is a fresh install. It is worth trying a repair (easy to do) and then proceed to a fresh install if required